# ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for

Tags: java, ejb, classloader, rmi

I'm getting the following exception:

```
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: com.client.itemmanager.ItemSessionHome (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)]
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:730)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:589)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.client.itemmanager.SessionLookupCounter.valueUnbound(SessionLookupCounter.java:45)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttributeInternal(StandardSession.java:1649)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:756)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,604 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:592)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.isRequestedSessionIdValid(Request.java:2134)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.parseSessionCookiesId(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:443)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:437)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:381)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: com.client.itemmanager.ItemSessionHome (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:531)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.system.JBossRMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(JBossRMIClassLoader.java:82)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1500)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,605 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1463)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:135)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.interfaces.MarshalledValuePair.get(MarshalledValuePair.java:72)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:654)
2011-01-05 13:47:51,606 ERROR [STDERR]  ... 14 more
```

I've done some research pointing to installing an RMI security manager like this:

```
if(System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
     System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
  }
```

I did verify that getSecurityManager() returns null, but shouldn't that only be needed if the EJB is on a remote machine? The EJB exists locally. Any advise on what may be setup wrong?

Comment: Would that be EJB3 or earlier?

Comment: There is a mix in this application :-P but this is an older style ejb.